# kafka consumer sessions timing out

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We have an application that a consumer reads a message and the thread does a number of things, including database accesses before a message is produced to another topic. The time between consuming and producing the message on the thread can take several minutes. Once message is produced to new topic, a commit is done to indicate we are done with work on the consumer queue message. Auto commit is disabled for this reason.

I'm using the high level consumer and what I'm noticing is that zookeeper and kafka sessions timeout because it is taking too long before we do anything on consumer queue so kafka ends up rebalancing every time the thread goes back to read more from consumer queue and it starts to take a long time before a consumer reads a new message after a while.

I can set zookeeper session timeout very high to not make that a problem but then i have to adjust the rebalance parameters accordingly and kafka won't pickup a new consumer for a while among other side effects.

What are my options to solve this problem? Is there a way to heartbeat to kafka and zookeeper to keep both happy? Do i still have these same issues if i were to use a simple consumer?

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you just explain your problem.  Saying you "would like to get some feedback" may get your question closed.  Stack Overflow is not a forum; we value being concise and to-the-point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like your problems boil down to relying on the high-level consumer to manage the last-read offset.  Using a simple consumer would solve that problem since you control the persistence of that offset.  Note that all the high-level consumer commit does is store the last read offset in zookeeper.  There's no other action taken and the message you just read is still there in the partition and is readable by other consumers.

With the kafka simple consumer, you have much more control over when and how that offset storage takes place.  You can even persist that offset somewhere other than Zookeeper (a data base, for example).

The bad news is that while the simple consumer itself is simpler than the high-level consumer, there's a lot more work you have to do code-wise to make it work.  You'll also have to write code to access multiple partitions - something the high-level consumer does quite nicely for you.

Comment: Hi, I am facing same problem, but in new kafka version, simple consumer is depreciated. How to do it now ?

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is consumer's poll method trigger consumer's heartbeat request. And when you increase session.timeout. Consumer's heartbeat will not reach to coordinator. Because of this heartbeat skipping, coordinator mark consumer dead. And also consumer rejoining is very slow especially in case of single consumer.

I have faced a similar issue and to solve that I have to change following parameter in consumer config properties

session.timeout.ms=
request.timeout.ms=more than session timeout

Also you have to add following property in server.properties at kafka broker node.
group.max.session.timeout.ms =

You can see the following link for more detail.
http://grokbase.com/t/kafka/users/16324waa50/session-timeout-ms-limit